Can I expand my /var partition?
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04, and I made a mistake: I put the /var directory on its own partition, and its size is 10 GB. After a few days it is already full.
Is there a way to fix this problem without reinstalling the OS from scratch?
Is it possible to resize a partition, even loosing its contents?
What is a suggested size for the /var directory?
This is my partition table:
Model: WD_BLACK SN850X 2000GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name   Flags
 8      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  fat32           boot   boot, esp
 1      1075MB  323GB   322GB   xfs             /
 2      323GB   426GB   103GB   linux-swap(v1)  swap   swap
 3      426GB   437GB   10.7GB  ext4            var
 4      437GB   439GB   2147MB  ext4            temp
 6      439GB   547GB   107GB   xfs             3rdp
 5      547GB   1406GB  859GB   ext4            home
 7      1406GB  1427GB  21.5GB  ext4            crypt

This is the contents of my /var directory:
~> sudo bash -c 'shopt -s dotglob; du -hxs /var/*'
7.0M    /var/backups
661M    /var/cache
4.0K    /var/crash
8.9G    /var/lib
4.0K    /var/local
0       /var/lock
49M     /var/log
16K     /var/lost+found
4.0K    /var/mail
4.0K    /var/metrics
4.0K    /var/opt
0       /var/run
13M     /var/snap
52K     /var/spool
108K    /var/tmp
4.0K    /var/.updated

Here are more details about my partitions:
~> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           5.9G  2.7M  5.9G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  300G   29G  272G  10% /
tmpfs            30G  180M   30G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M   12K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs        148K   62K   81K  44% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p6  100G  2.5G   98G   3% /opt
/dev/nvme0n1p7   20G   24K   19G   1% /crypt
/dev/nvme0n1p4  2.0G  103M  1.7G   6% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p3  9.8G  9.6G     0 100% /var
/dev/nvme0n1p5  787G   13G  734G   2% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p8 1022M   41M  982M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           5.9G  196K  5.9G   1% /run/user/1000


You can only manipulate a disk's partitions when none of them is mounted or in use as swap. You'll have to boot from some other medium (your install disk in "Try ..." mode, or a Live USB), and probably use swapoff before you run gparted. My /var is 137G, 10G used.

I'd be asking what filled up /var so quickly

Most new users do not need separate partitions over / (root). Often with larger drive like yours a separate /home may make sense. Extra partition then require you to manage space on each where having all in / requires less work allocating space correctly. You also have huge swap. You probably can reduce swap a lot and move /var into unallocated space and then expand right. Never interrupt move or data is corrupted. Be sure to have good backups before any partition change.

@ChrisDavies - I added the contents of my /var directory, if it can help.

Pietro thank you. I didn't realise you were going to do that. A better command might be ( shopt -s dotglob; du -hxs /var/* ), which will give you the size of each directory tree or file immediately underneath /var

@ChrisDavies - I used your command and updated my question. For many directories I have no permission to access (I omitted the error messages in my question). I tried with sudo ( ... ) and ( sudo ... ), but none works.

Ok. If you're not already root you need a little more complexity here. sudo bash -c 'shopt -s dotglob; du -hxs /var/*'. While you're editing your question, please also add the output from df -h (no root privilege required this time :-)

@ChrisDavies - I added the info you asked for.

@oldfred if one needs separate mount points like that the ZFS or Btrfs volumes are far better because they share the underlying physical space and "automatically expand" when needed

I'd suggest you put /var back onto / - plenty of space there

Resize hard drive partition to make more space for /var

The size of /var greatly depends on what the system is doing. For example, if the system is a mail server, /var/mail and  /var/spool could grow arbitrarily large, depending on the size of the user base; those directories would then effectively be the main reason of the system's existence.
The size of /var/lib depends on what software you have installed, and /var/cache and /var/snap might also grow depending on what applications are installed and how they are used.
You're using GPT and UEFI boot, but otherwise a quite classic partitioning setup. (GPT is good; it means we don't have to deal with MBR's size restrictions and the primary/extended/logical partition nonsense; all partitions will be equally usable for any purpose.)
If I'm not mistaken, there is still roughly 500G of unused space towards the end of the disk. And right next to the too-small /var partition, there's a swap partition of 103G. It could be repurposed to expand /var fairly easily. Unfortunately the swap is located before the /var partition, which complicates things a bit.
I would start by creating a new swap partition into the unused space, and running mkswap on it. Then I'd comment out the old swap partition in /etc/fstab, and add in the information of the new swap partition. At this point, I would also check if the suspend/resume configuration needs to be updated to point to the new swap partition (/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume in Debian, probably similar in Ubuntu). Then sudo update-initramfs -u and reboot.
After confirming the system is using the new swap partition and no longer the old one, it would be time to remove the swap flag from the old swap partition and set its partition type to be the same as /var has. Then the old swap could be initialized as the future /var using sudo mkfs.ext4, and mounted temporarily to /mnt.
Then, it would be time to shut down any applications that might be actively writing to /var, and copy the data from the old partition to the new one, with a simple cp -a /var/.updated /var/* /mnt/. Then another edit to /etc/fstab to make the system mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 instead of /dev/nvme0n1p3 as /var (probably using filesystem UUIDs though, as is the current recommended practice), and a reboot.
If the system now boots successfully with the new, expanded /var, it would be a simple matter to use gparted to remove the old, now-unused small /var and use its space to expand (even on-line!) the new /varstill further.
This is what I would do in this situation; you should use your own judgement to decide if this is a good plan for you or not.
If you need more specific instructions than this outline, you should consider doing this together with someone that has more Linux experience.

Thank you for your extensive explanation. Tomorrow I will try it.

I confirm I have 500 GB of free space. But I think I am stuck. I need to install gparted (sudo apt install gparted), and I get: E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/. I am thinking to reinstall the OS from scratch... with the knowledge that Ubuntu requires a larger /var partition than usual.

New SSD layout: delete existing /var; expand swap over the new available space (could not do it); create new 100GB wide /var in unused space. I think this should be fine for now.

What happened: the new /var I created in its own partition is not used, and the OS created a new /var directory in the / partition...

In order to mount any partition as /var, the root filesystem must have an (ideally empty) directory at /var to act as a mount point. So the /var directory in the / must always have been there. Your system just failed to mount the new /var, i.e. something is wrong with your /etc/fstab file, or you did not run a mkfs of appropriate type on the partition that was supposed to become the new /var.

There are insufficient data in your question from which to derive a meaningfully complete answer other than "maybe".
Is there unallocated space on the disk on which /var currently resides?  If so you may be able to use a tool such as parted or gparted to expand the partition.  If there is unused allocated space in another partition on the drive, the same tool might be able to be used to shrink that partition to make room for /var to expand.
Did you use a tool such as LVM to set up your disk allocation?  If so it may be possible to create a new physical partition and use LVM to utilize it to expand /var.
Absent knowing about these or other possible considerations, the only correct answer to give is "maybe".
As an aside, before you use any means to expand your /var allocation, it would be a good idea to ensure you have a good backup, because these operations do have a nonzero - albeit small - chance of causing data loss.

Thank you. Please, let me know if the information I added is enough.
